# Valor oculto da variável

Tags: c, variáveis, console

Quando coloco para mostrar os números que foram trocados o programa apenas não mostra nada, não entendi o porquê disso.

> Ler dois números, armazenando-os nas variáveis num1 e num2. Verificar
>   se o valor de num1 é maior que o valor de num2 e, em caso positivo,
>   trocar os conteúdos das variáveis

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
/*Ler dois números, armazenando-os nas variáveis num1 e num2. Verificar se o valor de
num1 é maior que o valor de num2 e, em caso positivo, trocar os conteúdos das variáveis*/


int num1, num2, x;
printf("Digite o valor do primeiro numero\n");
scanf("%d", &num1);
printf("Digite o valor do segundo numero\n");
scanf("%d", &num2);
x=num1;
if (num1<num2){
    num1=num2;
    num2=x;
    printf("O valor do primeiro numero é:\n", num2);
    printf("O valor do segundo numero é:\n", x);
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi bem tem que imprimir os dois valores originais de forma trocada, então não faz sentido não imprimir um deles e imprimir um valor temporário que é igual ao outro. O fato de não usar um nome de variável adequado ajuda cometer o erro. Além disto não está mandando imprimir o número, está só mandando um texto, para imprimir o número tem que dizer onde ele será colocado e usa-se neste caso o *placeholder* `%d` para um número inteiro. Tem mais erros de interpretação, assim fica melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Digite o valor do primeiro numero\n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Digite o valor do segundo numero\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    if (num1 > num2) {
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }
    printf("O valor do primeiro numero é: %d\n", num1);
    printf("O valor do segundo numero é: %d\n", num2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/SwapValuesConditionalc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SwapValuesConditional.c).

Answer (score 0):

Se num1 for maior que num2 vai imprimir eles trocados, caso contrário não acontecerá nada.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
/*Ler dois números, armazenando-os nas variáveis num1 e num2. Verificar se o valor de
num1 é maior que o valor de num2 e, em caso positivo, trocar os conteúdos das variáveis*/


int num1, num2, x;
printf("Digite o valor do primeiro numero\n");
scanf("%d", &num1);
printf("Digite o valor do segundo numero\n");
scanf("%d", &num2);
x=num1;
if (num1>num2){
    num1=num2;
    num2=x;
    printf("O valor do primeiro numero é: %d\n", num1);
    printf("O valor do segundo numero é: %d\n", num2);
}

return 0;

}
```